# Firebase Auth: link two pre-existing accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have read this:

> "Account linking can only be performed at the point at which a new
>   account is created. It is not possible, in other words, to link two
>   pre-existing accounts."

Is it still true?

I'd like this workflow :

1. User logs in the app and take his Anonymous uid;
2. Then User does the login (user previously registered) and obviously has his uid;

Now when the user does the logOut I'd like to give him his previous Anonymous uid, not a new one.
Is this possible?

Comment: Ti's answer is the correct one. You can't link 2 pre-existing accounts. If you have 2 users with different `uid`s, you can't link them. You would need to manually merge both user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to convert an anonymous account to a permanent account. You can do that by logging in the user into the new account, getting it's credential and then use it to link with the anonymous account, as mentioned on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account):

```
auth.currentUser.link(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
});
```

But when the user logs out, he can't get that previous uid back. Because anonymous accounts are temporary, as mentioned on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth):

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase

And I think it makes sense. Because if a user was anonymous, it means he has no identification. So there's no way you can tell who was using that uid before.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible if you want to link your anonymous user to an existing account. It will give you an error: 'auth/credential-already-in-use'. You have to manually merge your two accounts.

Comment: Is there an official documented account merger or is it completely DIY?

Comment: There is no official doc for that. Cuz it depends on what kind of data is associated with the user. Basically you'll need to copy the data from one use to the other and delete one of them.